# CSS Style to center a div

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the pricing table on this page centered: http://CloseDeals.co/sponsored

I'm using bootstrap so maybe there's a way to move the columns in?

It's currently justified to the left, but I want it centered.

Here's the code:

```
<section id="pricing" class="pricing">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row m-b-lg">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div class="navy-line"></div>
            <h1><span class="navy"><strong>Get 50% Off Through This Sponsored Link!</strong></span></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 wow zoomIn">
            <ul class="pricing-plan list-unstyled">
                <li class="pricing-title">
                    Monthly
                </li>
                <li class="pricing-desc">
                    21-day FREE Trial
                </li>
                <li class="pricing-price">
                    <s>$40</s> <span>$20</span>
                </li>
               <li>
                    Unlimited Sequences
                </li>
                <li>
                    Unlimited Active Contacts
                </li>
                <li>
                    Un-Sponsored Emails
                </li>
                <li>
                    Email & Chat Support
                </li>
                <li>
                    Import Contacts
                </li>
                <li>
                    API & Zapier Access
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 wow zoomIn">
            <ul class="pricing-plan list-unstyled selected">
                <li class="pricing-title">
                    Annual
                </li>
                <li class="pricing-desc">
                    21-day FREE Trial
                </li>
                <li class="pricing-price">
                  <s>$400</s> <span>$200</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Unlimited Sequences
                </li>
                <li>
                    Unlimited Active Contacts
                </li>
                <li>
                    Un-Sponsored Emails
                </li>
                <li>
                    Email & Chat Support
                </li>
                <li>
                    Import Contacts
                </li>
                <li>
                    API & Zapier Access
                </li>
                <li>
                    <strong>2 Months FREE!</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m-t-lg">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center m-t-lg">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="http://app.closedeals.co/users/sign_up/fbs">Start Your 21-Day FREE Trial</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</div>

</section>
```

I tried adding:

```
<div class="container" align="center">
```

Comment: Can you post your code and what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks. I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the page have bootstrap so you can use an offset class, i tried in the inspector an offset of 2 and seem nice

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 wow zoomIn animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: zoomIn;">
```

you can try another values if you wish:

**col-lg-offset-2**

here is more info:
[bootstrap grid offseting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with flexbox you put this code to the parent of the two boxes

```
 YOUR CONTAINER{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to offset the first pricing table?

You could add an offset to the first item.

`<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 wow zoomIn animated">`